# How can I end a functions execution from a spy?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I have an express function. It checks if an `id_token` is provided before it continues. `response.json({})` would return an http-response and stop the execution of the code. So I can write this and `// do whatever` is never run.

```
function( request, response ) {
  if( !request.query.id_token )
    response.status(400).json({message: 'id_token has not been provided'});
  
  // do whatever
}
```

However when writing unit tests I decided to create a spy for the response object.

```
class ResponseSpy {
  constructor() {
    this.result = {};
  }
  json( json ) {
    this.result.json = json;
  }
  status( code ) {
    this.result.code = code;
    return this;
  }
}
```

I would run the test like this (using mocha as test-runner and the assert-module in node.js ):

```
describe('subscribe( request, response)', () => {
  it('should throw an error when id_token is not provided', () => {
    //  arrange
    const request = { query: {}};
    const response = new ResponseSpy();
    // act
    firebase_functions.subscribe( request, response );
    // assert
    const result = response.result;
    assert.strictEqual( result.code, 400 );
    assert.deepStrictEqual( result.json, {message: 'id_token has not been provided'} );
  });
});
```

This works. But I am using a spy for the json-method. This spy does not end the code execution. So the code continues and bad things happen in the `// do whatever` part.

I can work around this with an else block.

```
function( request, response ) {
  if( !request.query.id_token ) {
    response.status(400).json({message: 'id_token has not been provided'});
  } else {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

That would potentially lead to a bunch of embedded if/else statements. Which I am not very keen of.

So it would be preferable to stop the code from the spy, just like the original `response.json()` method does. **How can I end a functions execution from a spy?**

Comment: `response.json` *doesn't* stop the function. The only way you could from the test double is to throw an error. FWIW I wouldn't test an Express function like this at all, use e.g. Supertest to write a more integration-level test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You are correct, `response.json()` doesn't stop the function. So that means it is a bug in my express-function. I fixed it with a `return;` in my if-statement to stop code-execution and everything works as expected now.